# PHPBB 3 error while disapprove a post

Tags: phpbb3

Hi I have installed `PHPBB3` and I tried to disapprove a post and i am getting following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException'
>   with message 'The service definition
>   "phpbb.report.report_reason_list_provider" does not exist.' in
>   /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:871
>   Stack trace: 0
>   /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(478):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('phpbb.report.re...')
>   1 /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/includes/mcp/mcp_queue.php(1245): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('phpbb.report.re...')
>   2 /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/includes/mcp/mcp_queue.php(122): mcp_queue::disapprove_posts(Array, 'queue', 'unapproved_post...') #3
>   /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/includes/functions_module.php(674):
>   mcp_queue->main('queue', 'unapproved_post...') #4
>   /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/mcp.php(311): p_master->load_active() #5
>   {main} in
>   /var/www/html/ddugky/forum/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php
>   on line 871

I found out reason because `phpbb` did not contain reports folder and now i created report folder and its contents yet again same error is displayed

Can anyone please help